# shouldn't PHP array recursion throw an error?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, pass-by-reference

This is the test and the response I get. I think this could be problematic and should throw an error or a notice but I cannot understand why is tolerated.

```
<?php
    $test = array( 0 => 'test', 1=> &$test );
    var_dump( $test );

    // array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "test" [1]=> &array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "test" [1]=> &array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "test" [1]=> *RECURSION* } } }
?>
```

Comment: I’m rather surprised that you can reference `$test` in the same expression that defined `$test`. `$test = array('test'); $test[]=&$test;` is pretty clear. But yours …

Comment: This is not a real problem and I was surprised as well. I was just playing with arrays and hit a personal dilema.

Comment: @Gumbo PHP is weird. You can assign references before the value exists: `$x =& $y; $y = 5;` for example is valid, with `$y` having never been defined earlier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is true recursion, and `*RECURSION*` is not a real error message.
It's not problematic, because `$test` is not actively recurring, and in this case `var_dump` is smart enough to stop before exhausting memory.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that detecting such a loop is non-trivial, and would be immediately apparent at runtime if the behaviour was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Why is it problematic? PHP is smart enough to identify that an array is being recursively called.

The same happens if you `print_r($GLOBALS)`, I see no harm in this.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting a reference, that is, a pointer so there is no true recursion, no loop.  So no, it shouldn't throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Actualy the `*RECURSION*` message is a error message, which ends the script execution.
Else it would execute it till the memory limit is reaced.